# How do I persist state for android apps killed in the background in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

When an Android App is sent to the background, it can persist its instance state in case it gets killed due to low memory (see [Activity:onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and the bundle argument for [Activity:onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))).

The default Activity behaviour is saving the state of the view hierarchy so for a lot of cases you don't have to write any code and it "just works"[tm].

Now for react-native this is not true. React native apps are hosted in a single MainActivity and their state is contained in the javascript interpreter in the app.

I created a sample repository with short documentation how to reproduce my problem here: https://github.com/einvalentin/react-native-state-test

I would want react-native to hook into the native android app state serialisation mechanism while providing application developers hooks to extend if they need custom serialisation. Alternatively I could see myself extending the MainActivity to forward the lifecycle events to the Javascript layer and do some custom state serialisation manually there - but this feels a bit clunky.

Is there an obvious way I have overlooked to save the state in react-native so that apps that are killed in the background are not restarted from scratch? This can always happen for example on low memory devices receiving a phone call while interacting with your app.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution to this, @Valentin? Struggling with the same thing. Native Android handles this quite well where as React Native just wipes your stack and starts over from scratch. We played around with https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html but it's limited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using Redux for state management you should probably use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). If not you have a couple of different options:

- [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)
- [Realm React Native](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/)

Comment: Thanks! So that would basically boil down to me sending onSaveInstanceState() & the iOS State Preservation & Restoration hooks down to react-native and persist the redux store.

Comment: If you're using redux, just use redux-persist. Would appreciate an accepted answer. ;)