# How to call API when App is killed in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, ios-background-mode, uibackgroundmode

I Want to call API in the background when App killed and set the data in AsyncStorage. I used the following library but not working for me.

**[react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)**

**[react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)**

I want to called the API without time scheduling. The above both use the time Scheduling.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to implement the `componentWillUnmount` method on the root of your app or use a library like realm to save the state throughout the use of your app.

Maybe worth checking out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350708/how-do-i-persist-state-for-android-apps-killed-in-the-background-in-react-native?rq=1)

Comment: There is nothing happened after calling api and adding any console in componentWillUnmount. Can you please show me any working demo?

Comment: I have implemented `componentWillUnmount ` inside my root component, but nothing happened.