# Lifecycle Management in React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, lifecycle, react-lifecycle

What is the life cycle when exiting an app with Swipe in Ios Simulator? I tried to log every lifecycle, but nothing happened. I want to execute a specific function when the app exits, but I'm not sure what to do. Has anyone had a similar problem with me?

Comment: By exiting do you mean actually killing the app? swiping it away?

Comment: @Auticcat killing the app

Comment: Use `applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)` function in iOS. From there you can call your shared React-Native component functions

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023044/how-to-call-api-when-app-is-killed-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to detect if the app is closing, but you can check if the app is in background using `AppState`.

In your parent component, add:

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

...

componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}

...

_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    //based of nextAppState, do what you need
}
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Answer (score 0):

In iOS AppDelegate.swift

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // get your shared RCTView
    sharedRCTView.appProperties = [..., "isTerminate": true];
}
```

In React-Native Component

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(nextProps.isTerminate!==prevState.isTerminate){
     // Do your stuff
     return { someState: nextProps.isTerminate};
  }
  else return null;
}
```

Comment: hi, any solutions for functional component?